# Autosize comment box in Excel 2016 for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2016

I've updated to Excel 2016 and the following code which worked in Excel 2011 generates this error.

[image: Run-time error '1004' Method 'TextFrame' of object 'Shape' failed]

```vb
Dim Commnt As Comment
    
For Each Commnt In Application.ActiveSheet.Comments ' Autosize all comment boxes on the sheet
    Commnt.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
Next
```

How is the task of autosizing all the worksheet comments in Excel 2016 accomplished?

After further research, I tried the following WITHOUT success.

```vb
Dim Shp As Shape
For Each Shp In wks1.Shapes
    With Shp.TextFrame2
        .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
        .WordWrap = msoTrue
    End With
Next Shp
```

Comment: That's a weird error, because TextFrame isn't a method it's a property.

Comment: Do you get same error if you use `TextFrame2`? And does this error happen on ALL comments or only some of them?

Comment: You have seven potential causes for that error in the snippet of code you posted. Either `Application`, `ActiveSheets` or `Comments` in the first line, or `Commnt`, `Shape`, or `TextFrame` are not valid (the first six), or `AutoSize` does not exist as a property of `TextFrame` (the seventh). Use the debugger to figure out which is causing the issue.

Comment: Your second attempt is iterating over `Shapes` collection, not the `Comments` collection.

Comment: Although on trying it out with the answer given below, it also does not work.

Comment: Unfortuantely, it looks like this is not possible without direclty manipulating the size of the comment itself, which will be a rather herculean effort to determine how big it *should* be based on the characters, font, etc., and you'll likely end up having to coerce line breaks otherwise you'll end up with long/narrow comments all on a single line.

Comment: Why does the second attempt not resize the comment box shapes to fit the comment text and any other shapes with text?

Answer (score 0):

As documented in MSDN, the TextFrame (and TextFrame2) properties of Comment are read-only in Excel 2016.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shape-textframe-property-excel
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shape-textframe2-property-excel

A quick test with Excel 365 showed that autosizing the comment can be achieved using the Autosize property of the Shape object itself.

```
Dim Commnt As Comment

For Each Commnt In Application.ActiveSheet.Comments ' Autosize all comment boxes on the sheet
    Commnt.Shape.AutoSize = True
Next
```

However this does not look to be valid with Excel 2016.

Comment: Removing the TextFrame causes the compile error "Method or data member not found" when running the macro.  Previous to posting, I'd reviewed the MSDN reference material, but not found a. solution or understood how to fix my issue.

Comment: Perhaps Mac OS Excel has a Comment.Shape.Autosize property, but Windows OS does not. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/comment-object-excel

Comment: Thanks everyone for your consideration and time!  However, is there no way to size the comment box to the comments?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveWorkbook.DisplayDrawingObjects = xlDisplayShapes
```

Check your workbook property, if shape is not available, calling autosize will cause the error.
[Workbook.DisplayDrawingObjects property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.displaydrawingobjects)